# Live stock value from Google finance

Tags: solidity

How to link live data from Google finance to a token? Can select LIVE stock values be displayed in the token?

Comment: What you are defining is an Oracle. Basically a node whose purpose is to provide a link between (real world) data and the blockchain, see https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/oracles/

Comment: God bless you. Will learn